# Debugging the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on Iphone using Performance Tool, Allocations

Tags: iphone

An error is caught, using Zombie 
CFString    Foundation Library
caller  {NSPlaceholderMutableString int] Malloc

CFString    Foundation Library
 caller  {NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale} Zombie

well it didn't drop to where I declared. I have no idea where that NSMutablestring is called and which variable it is

Answer (score 1):

- Instruments provides an option to record reference counts -- ensure it's enabled.
- Run your app and reproduce the issue.
- When Instruments halts the program due to messaging a zombie, it will tell you the address of the zombie.
- You then locate the address in the list of allocations and view the location it was created, as well as all its ref count ops.

It takes about 2 minutes to spot an issue once you get the hang of it, and can reproduce the problem. Good luck.

Also, 0x8badf00d has recommended *"session 311 Advanced Memory analysis with Instruments."* below. I've not watched it personally, but it sounds like it would be a great session on the subject.

Comment: +1 I would recommend @lilzz to watch session 311 Advanced Memory analysis with Instruments.