# objc: strong property with NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, memory-leaks

I declare a strong property:

`@property (strong) NSString *message;`

And I set the message like:

```
self.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx %@",sth];
```

But it will crashed with message:

```
*** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1015ea790
```

Even I change the property: strong-> copy, it still crashes.
Now I fixed it using:

```
self.message = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx %@",sth] copy];
```

But I still can't understand it as I always write it in the same way in iOS.

By the way: the code is for cocoa, no-arc

Update1:

1 I have added `@synthesize message;`

2 sth is an example, the real code is

```
self.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx %@", [[NSDate date] description]];
```

3 I remember the default implementation for the strong/copy property can be like:

```
- (void)setMessage:(NSString*)newMsg
{
   if (message != newMsg)
   {
        [newMsg retain];
        [message release];
        message = newMsg;
   }
}
```

SO I think the property-synthesis will add the copy/retain for me.
That's what makes me confused!

Comment: What is `sth` in the example above?

Comment: we need a code example that you can run to show this problem... because this isn't really how they are supposed to work.

Comment: I don't think strong means anything outside of ARC... so just copy should work...

Comment: @GradyPlayer I'm pretty sure that `strong` is treated as `retain` in a non-ARC project.

Comment: Did you synthesize the accessors?

Comment: `+stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased instance of NSString. You either need an explicit retain, or keep that copy call (it performs a retain on immutable strings).  I'd also check to see if you're overriding the setter for this thing, because `retain` and `strong` should handle that explicit `retain` for you

Comment: @CodaFi if the property is strong, then assigning an autoreleased object is fine, no explicit retining is needed.

Comment: @scorpiozj By the way, you are confusing the two possible variations of the setter method. It's enough to retain first and release only then **or** check pointer inequality and release first and retain only then.

Comment: @H2CO3, I just synthesize it. The setter method above is used for instruction for the memory management which I think the objc does the all for me. And the property "message" which still receives the over-release message is a big trouble for me.

Comment: The really problem is I release the message in the dealloc, but I never alloc it in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative reference count imbalance lies in code which has not been posted.

This variant is wrong:

```
self.message = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx %@",sth] copy];
```

-- that just introduces a positive reference count imbalance (hallmark side effect: leaked objects).

First, fix all analyzer warnings. If that does not fix it, then run Instruments. It can record the reference count operations for each object: [Debugging the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on Iphone using Performance Tool, Allocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640309/debugging-the-exec-bad-access-on-iphone-using-performance-tool-allocations/8640502#8640502)

Note which will not solve the problem: you should use `copy` for your `NSString` property rather than `strong`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are trying to set the string using a setter method before instantiating the string object in the alloc method.

Make sure you instantiate the String object in the alloc method.

While in the second case you are assigning a copied object to the property. that's why you don't see the error.